# How to solve n + 1 problem in hibernate for my case?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, thymeleaf

I have a problem with n + 1 select in hibernate. I looked at a lot of articles on this topic, but I could not understand what my mistake was.

My query:

```
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, UUID> {
 @Query("SELECT c from Client c LEFT JOIN Subscription s on c.company.id = s.company.id WHERE s.id LIKE '%trial%' order by c.firstName ASC")  
 List<Client> getAllTrials();
}
```

Subscription Entity:

```
       @Entity
        public class Subscription implements Serializable {
          @Id
          private String id;
       
          @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
          @JoinColumn
          private Company company;
      
          @NotNull
          private OffsetDateTime time;
          
          @NotNull
          private SubscriptionStatus status;
     //getters and setters + constructors = ...
```

Client entity:

```
    @Entity
    public class Client implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      private UUID id;
    
      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn
      private Company company;
    
      @NotBlank
      private String firstName;
    
      @NotBlank
      private String lastName;
    
      @NotBlank
      private String email;

...
```

Company Entity:

```
    @Entity
    public class Company implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      private UUID id;
    
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
      @JsonIgnoreProperties("company")
      private List<Client> clients;
    
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
      private List<Subscription> subscriptions = new ArrayList<>();

...
```

[image: My tables in DB]

When I try to get these attributes hibernate is using too many queries.

```
 model.addAttribute ("trialUsers", clientService.getAllTrialClients ());
 
<table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Surname</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>time</td>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>status</td>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr th:each="client : ${trialUsers}">
        <td th:text="${client.firstName}"></td>
        <td th:text="${client.lastName}"></td>
        <td th:text="${client.email}"></td>
        <td th:text="${client.company.subscriptions[0].time}"></td>
        <td th:text="${client.company.subscriptions[0].id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${client.company.subscriptions[0].status}"></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `JOIN FETCH` ? See https://vladmihalcea.com/n-plus-1-query-problem/ for more info.

Comment: I tried using fetch but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

`@NamedEntityGraph` will solve your problem.

You need to create the `NamedEntityGraph` as shown below.

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.ClientAndCompany", attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "company") })
```

You can use define it on your `Client`  `Entity`

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.ClientAndCompany", attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "company") })
@Entity
public class Client implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      private UUID id;
    
      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn
      private Company company;
    
      @NotBlank
      private String firstName;
    
      @NotBlank
      private String lastName;
    
      @NotBlank
      private String email;

...
```

Then you need to use it on your repository method as

```
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, UUID> {

 @EntityGraph(value = "graph.ClientAndCompany", type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
 @Query("SELECT c from Client c LEFT JOIN Subscription s on c.company.id = s.company.id WHERE s.id LIKE '%trial%' order by c.firstName ASC")  
 List<Client> getAllTrials();

}
```

you can find more details [here](https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Interesting article. But for some reason this does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

#### Maybe it isn't a very good solution, but now i have 4 selects instead of n+1.

```
 @Query("from Subscription s where s.id like '%trial%'")
  List<Subscription> findAllSubTrial();

@Query("SELECT c from Client c LEFT JOIN Subscription s on c.company.id = s.company.id WHERE s.id LIKE '%trial%' order by c.firstName ASC")
  List<Client> getAllTrials();

model.addAttribute ("clients", clientService.getAllTrialClients ());
model.addAttribute("subscriptions", subscriptionService.findAllSubTrial ());
model.addAttribute("standardDate", new Date());

<table>
          <thead>
          <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>last name</td>
          <td>Email</td>
          <td>time</td>
          <td>extend period</td>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr role="row" th:each="client:${clients}">
            <td th:text="${client.firstName}">
            <td th:text="${client.lastName}">
            <td th:text="${client.email}">
            <td>
              <input type="date" th:each="subscription : ${subscriptions}"
                 th:if="(${subscription.company.id} == ${client.company.id})"
                 th:value="${#temporals.format(subscription.time, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"
                 th:min="${#temporals.format(subscription.time, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"
                     th:id='${subscription.id}'>
            <td>
      
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```